# Wordpress create new register category?

Tags: wordpress

I would like to create new register group category. I have one category global in post, but I create new plugin and then I want to create new category. My code:

```
function movie_create_taxonomy() {
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'movie' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'movie_create_taxonomy' );
```

Then I have the one place with category and I would like new group category only use this plugin `movie`. This is not good because when I run loop for category I print all category but I need only category in `movie` plugin.

How to create the new register category? I find only taxonomies but this is not exactly that what I want:
[register taxonomy](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy)

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

```
function movie_create_taxonomy() {

    /**
     * Taxonomy: Categories.
     */

    $labels = array(
        "name" => __( "Categories", "" ),
        "singular_name" => __( "Categories", "" ),
    );

    $args = array(
        "label" => __( "Categories", "" ),
        "labels" => $labels,
        "public" => true,
        "hierarchical" => true,
        "label" => "Categories",
        "show_ui" => true,
        "show_in_menu" => true,
        "show_in_nav_menus" => true,
        "query_var" => true,
        "rewrite" => array( 'slug' => 'category', 'with_front' => true, ),
        "show_admin_column" => false,
        "show_in_rest" => false,
        "rest_base" => "",
        "show_in_quick_edit" => false,
    );
    register_taxonomy( "category", array( "movie" ), $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'movie_create_taxonomy' );
```